# Angular group comma separated values in select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm having this problem i can't group this comma separated values in select dropdown options, here is my code:

**here is the model:**

[image]

**Angular code:**

```
<select ng-model="attrModel" ng-options="option.Value group by option.Key.Name for option in attrModel track by option.Value"></select>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Expceted Result:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried pre-processing the data and calling .split()?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass the whole `Value` array as the value to the `<option>` tag.

I am not 100% sure how to handle nested arrays within a select properly but you can use [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) for it.

```
<select ng-model="myFixedSelection">
  <optgroup ng-repeat="group in attrModel track by $index" label="{{group.Key.Name}}">
    <option ng-repeat="value in group.Value track by $index" >{{ value }}</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

See the working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LtMHOFVuOQhLAqMYPTGL?p=preview)